# Fake data stub for android authorisations

Tags: android, permissions

I'm annoyed by all the applications on my Android device that require access to media/camera/message/call etc, when they don't really need them.

Is there a way to fake the autorisations? Like having an empty media-folder/call-history for application that needs media/call? Most of them won't work if you don't give every permission they ask for.

I don't want all permissions revoked. I am looking for a way to fake it.

Note: I'm on a BlackBerry Priv

Comment: if they are asking for it, they are using it. For example: a application that do not really much  (maybe just a android client for some kind of service) has microphone and internet access. Internet Access: Ok the service is in the Internet but Microphone? It can then use some kind of Audio Beaconing like SilverPush. But in the end: as far I don't really think you could fake these thinks without modify the Android Stock system and/or the Linux under it.

Comment: @Serverfrog When I say `don't really need them` I mean, those permissions are used for stuff I don't ask the application to do.